# Potential issue with Parse.com JavaScript SDK (1.2.13).?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I'm wondering if there is a issue with the parse.com JavaScript SDK (1.2.13).

The below I thought is pretty simple, it queries the "myBadges" class and should only return results to the current user that is logged in. But as you can see from the screen shot it returns all results found in myBadges.

It would seem there is an issue using

```
query.equalTo("uploadedBy",currentUser);
```

to return results?

I've removed the results section of the code to limit the length of this post, but I know from dev tools all results are returned.

Results show for a3aePaphBF but current user is UfFi7l3VBc.

I've made quite a few edits and changes to my _User class, is it best to delete and start again with this?

HTML

```
<form>
        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" /> 
        <button id="find_button" type="button" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
</form>
```

JS

```
var friendName;
var UsersBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
var usersBadges = new UsersBadges();
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

// Captures the input from user and checks if the name already exists within the Db.
function findFriend() {
    friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    console.log(friendName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(UsersBadges);
    query.equalTo("uploadedBy",currentUser); // find users that match
   query.find({
        success: function (friendMatches) {
         //results}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try this with the newest version? 1.2.18

Comment: @Fosco ok, done same issue...which is leading me back to an error with the code. :-/

Comment: can you try query.equalTo("uploadedBy",currentUser.id); ?

Comment: @Fosco that helped, it lead me to removing all users from _User and starting again, which then returned correct results when using currentUser. However when I try and use friendName as the filter point it still is'nt working. Must be an issue with that variable?